# Sum of to arrays with different array sizes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to solve sum of to array problem:

```
//[1,2,3] + [1,2] should be [1,3,5]
```

I'm able to solve this if the array are the same size, but how can I deal with different array sizes?
Here is my code for now:

```
function sumOfArrays(a, b) {

    let result = new Array(Math.max(a.length, b.length)); 
    let carry = 0;

    for (let i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const elementA = a[i];
        const elementB = b[i];
        const additionResult = elementA + elementB + carry;
        result[i] = (additionResult % 10);
        carry = Math.floor(additionResult / 10);
    }
}
```

I'm basically getting null values into the result array If there is a difference in the size of the array

Comment: const elementA = a[i] || 0

Comment: But for this to work you would need i to go from 1 to n and subtract it from the corresponding array length. Otherwise you pad right instead of left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a comparison if the 2 arrays are the same length.

If not, you can 'pad' it from the beginning with `0`'s until ther are the same length.

Then your code will work as expected (after adding `return result` ;) )

```js
const pad = (arr, size, fill = 0) => [ ...Array(size - arr.length).fill(0), ...arr ];

let a = [1,2,3];
let b = [1,2];

if (a.length < b.length) {
    a = pad(a, b.length);
} else if (b.length < a.length) {
    b = pad(b, a.length);
}

function sumOfArrays(a, b) {

    let result = new Array(Math.max(a.length, b.length)); 
    let carry = 0;

    for (let i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const elementA = a[i];
        const elementB = b[i];
        const additionResult = elementA + elementB + carry;
        result[i] = (additionResult % 10);
        carry = Math.floor(additionResult / 10);
    }
    
    return result;
}

const res = sumOfArrays(a, b);
console.log(res)
```

---

However, since the array's are now the same length, we can simplefy the code a lot by using `map()` and add (`+`) to current value of the other array on that index:

```js
const pad = (arr, size, fill = 0) => [ ...Array(size - arr.length).fill(0), ...arr ];

let a = [1,2,3];
let b = [1,2];

if (a.length < b.length) {
    a = pad(a, b.length);
} else if (b.length < a.length) {
    b = pad(b, a.length);
}

function sumOfArrays(a, b) {
    return a.map((n, i) => n + b[i]);
}

const res = sumOfArrays(a, b);
console.log(res)
//  [
//    1,
//    3,
//    5
//  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an offset for the index to add.

```js
function add(a, b) {
    const
        length = Math.max(a.length, b.length),
        offsetA = a.length - length,
        offsetB = b.length - length;

    return Array.from(
        { length },
        (_, i) => (a[i + offsetA] || 0) + (b[i + offsetB] || 0)
    );
}

console.log(...add([1, 2, 3], [1, 2])); // [1, 3, 5]
console.log(...add([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])); 
console.log(...add([1, 2, 3, 4], [1])); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
console.log(...add([1], [1, 2, 3, 4])); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
```